# Implementing web service using NuSOAP in CakePHP

Tags: php, web-services, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, nusoap

I've written my code as shown below:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeTime', 'Utility');
App::import('Vendor', 'Nusoap', array('file' => 'Nusoap' . DS . 'lib' . DS . 'nusoap.php'));

class ApiController extends AppController {

    /**
     * Controller name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $name = 'Api';
    public $uses = array();

    function index() {
        $server = new soap_server();
        $server->configureWSDL("Testing WSDL ", "urn:Testing WSDL ", "http://localhost/test/api");

        $server->register("gethelloworld", array("name" => "xsd:string"), array("return" => "xsd:string"), "urn:helloworld", "urn:helloworld#gethelloworld");

        function gethelloworld($name) {
            $myname = "My Name Is <b>" . $name . "</b>";
            return $myname;
        }

        $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
        $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
    }

}
```

But whenever I run it, I get the following notice:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: _transient [APP\Vendor\Nusoap\lib\nusoap.php, line 226]
```

Am I missing something here? Here is the screenshot when I call `http://localhost/test/api`

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Double check your files and configuration. With your setup (i'm using CakePHP v2.4.0) I have no issue:

[image]